# Checking whether points form a polygon in complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, roots

If z^8=(z-1)^8 then the roots are
1) concyclic
2) form a polygonal
3)none

I found the roots to be 1+cot(k.pi/8) for k is a natural number and less than 8.

Then couldn't figure it out.

Comment: 1.what "cot(x)" stands for ? $e^{xi}$  ? 
2. what have you tried, did you try to draw the points in the complex plain  ?

Comment: There are 7 solutions, one real and six complex. The real part of each solution is $\frac{1}{2}$, so all the solutions lie on the line $z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the complex homography $$z \to f(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}$$

$f$ is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)). So its inverse is equal to itself.

The solutions of the equation $Z^8=1$ are concyclic: they are on the unit circle. The solutions of your initial equation are located on the image of the unit circle by the complex homography $f$.

As the pole of $f$, namely $1$ belongs to the unit circle, the image of the the unit circle by $f$ is a line. Hence the solutions of the equation of your post lie on a line.

Comment: This is nice. I went the long way about it and kept breaking the problem down to use the quadratic formula. It's hot here in Montana as well.